# Set enablePushState = false on specific urls inside Pjax container (Yii2)

Tags: yii2, pjax

I need pjax to work on change status click and it's working fine but don't want it to change the URL as well. Below is the code:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'pjax-container-agency-index', 'timeout' => 10000, 'enablePushState' => true]); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([...,
             [
                'label' => 'Status',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    if ($data->deactive == 0) {
                        return Html::a(FA::i('circle'), ['agency/change-status', 'id' => $data->member_id, 'set' => 1], ['onclick' => "return confirm('Deactive this state/site?');", 'class' => 'status-inactive']);
                    } else {
                        return Html::a(FA::i('circle'), ['agency/change-status', 'id' => $data->member_id, 'set' => 0], ['onclick' => "return confirm('Active this state/site?');", 'class' => 'status-active']);
                    }
                },
             ],
]);
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

`actionChangeStatus()` is as below:

```
public function actionChangeStatus($id, $set) {
    if (!empty($id) && isset($set)) {
        $localGovt = $this->findModel($id);
        $localGovt->deactive = $set;
        if ($localGovt->save()) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success-status', 'State Status Changed');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error-status', 'There is some error. Please consult with Admin.');
        }
        $searchModel = new AgencySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
           'searchModel' => $searchModel,
           'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I need `'enablePushState' => true` for other events, so I can't change it to `false` inside `Pjax::begin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's

```
'enableReplaceState' => true
```

Comment: can you add a bit more detail to your answer , where exactly do you have to pass the name=?value pair in the `column` config or `pjax`

Answer (score 0):

Pass this attribute to Pjax: 

`Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]);`

This worked for me.